# How to share service between tests in vertx

Tags: java, junit4, vert.x

I wrote a small example of an issue I am having with sharing a service between a set of test classes. What I did was write a base class and extend it in the other classes.

```
@RunWith(VertxUnitRunner.class)
public abstract class BaseTest {

    @ClassRule
    public static final RunTestOnContext contextRule = new RunTestOnContext();

    @ClassRule
    public static final Timeout timeout = Timeout.seconds(2);

    static HelloService service;

    @BeforeClass
    public static void setupClass(TestContext context) {
        contextRule.vertx().exceptionHandler(context.exceptionHandler());
        contextRule.vertx().deployVerticle(new HelloVerticle(), context.asyncAssertSuccess(result -> {
            Assertions.assertThat(result).isNotBlank();
        }));
        service = HelloService.createProxy(contextRule.vertx(), VERTX_HELLO_SERVICE);
    }

    @AfterClass
    public static void teardownClass(TestContext context) {
        contextRule.vertx().close(context.asyncAssertSuccess());
    }
}
```

And I have two test classes.

```
public class HelloTest extends BaseTest {

    @Test
    public void test(TestContext context) {
        service.hello("John", context.asyncAssertSuccess(r -> {
           assertThat(r).isEqualTo("Hello John");
        }));
    }
}
```

and

```
public class Hello2Test extends BaseTest {
    @Test
    public void test(TestContext context) {
        service.hello("John2", context.asyncAssertSuccess(r -> {
           assertThat(r).isEqualTo("Hello John2");
        }));
    }
}
```

Each class can run individually but when they are run together from intellij or from the `mvn test`, one class will run and the tests will freeze and never fail. Even with the timeout rule.

What is causing this issue and is there a better solution to sharing the service in other tests. My goal is to not need to startup the verticle multiple times in the tests.

These tests are in junit4. I added the example repo [here](https://github.com/moaxcp/vertx-examples).

Comment: what does the hello method do? Is that deadlocking? I do think they are using different service objects

Comment: It is in the linked repo. `"Hello %s".formatted(name)`.